# What is this syntax in Node.js and PostGres

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Hi came across this syntax in a node.js application, in which we are making a SELECT query to our postgres database.

```
app.get("/monsters/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    pool.query(`SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE id = $1`, [id], (err, response) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
        console.log(response.rows);
        res.send(response.rows);
    })
});
```

I **don't understand the follow the line**:
pool.query(`SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE id = $1`, [id], (err, response) => {

how does this kind of string literal work, where we have used $1 and passing an array?

Thank you

Comment: That's a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Also `$1` is not connected to the string literal - it's just a normal part of the text inside. It's used by the SQL engine to be replaced with an appropriate parameter.

Comment: it is adding the first element of the [id] array. So what does $1 represent?

Comment: It's the parameter in the array. It's just a parametarised query.

Comment: Thank you, so again this has to do with SQL syntax and not JS ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance While the string is stored as a template string there are no interpolation done here. The template string is a red-herring and this code would work the same way if you replace it with a regular string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with javascript or node.js syntax. The string

```
`SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE id = $1`
```

is the same as:

```
"SELECT * FROM monsters WHERE id = $1"
```

because there is no interpolation done within the string.

From the point of javascript, `$1` literally represents `$1` and nothing else.

I don't quite know the library you are using for accessing postgres but it looks fairly obvious to me that `$1` is mapped to the first element of `[id]` (which is just the value of `id`). It looks like the postgres library used maps `$1` to `?` in SQL syntax and moves the values in the second argument to the appropriate part of the generated sql query.

I would look at the documentation for the library used to access postgres for more info on the API.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so confused by that syntax. But this clears it up!